# iphone - How to center dynamic sized text

Tags: iphone, uitextview, uilabel

I have text that I want to display centered (both vertically and horizontally) within bounds of a box.  The text is dynamic so I can't just set it in IB.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: [This can be your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12591299/1603234)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following method to get the expected size as

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font];
```

Using this set the frame of your label as

```
yourLabel.frame = CGRectMake( yourX, yourY, expectedLabelSize.width , expectedLabelSize.height;
```

The same could be done with UIButton and UItextArea. You can also you use UITextField but the height would not be adjustible.

Also you can set the `textalignment` property to Centre as `yourLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter`

Hope it works!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't see how this vertically aligns my text.

Comment: yeah ..... you are ryt .... i am also not sure of the vertical alignment..... as far as i know there is no in built way to align the same.... :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the height from the contentSize property of a UITextView to set the contentOffset property of a UITextView such that the text height is centered in the text view's frame height.  Similar for width.  A text view does not have to be editable if you just want to display text.

You could also use a UIWebView containing appropriate CSS to center content.

Answer (score 0):

Modify setAutoresizingMask property to your needs