# Center text vertically in a UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextview

I want to center the text *vertically* inside a big `UITextView` that fills the whole screen - so that when there's little of text, say a couple of words, it is centered by height.
It's not a question about centering the text (a property that can be found in IB) but about putting the text *vertically* right in the middle of `UITextView` *if* the text is short, so there are no blank areas in the `UITextView`.
Can this be done?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

First add an observer for the `contentSize` key value of the `UITextView` when the view is loaded:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
     [textField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
     [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Then add this method to adjust the `contentOffset` every time the `contentSize` value changes:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
     UITextView *tv = object;
     CGFloat topCorrect = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv contentSize].height * [tv zoomScale])/2.0;
     topCorrect = ( topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect );
     tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
}
```

Comment: This works great for me until the UITextView is filled with text and starts to scroll. Then the view bounces for each new character. I put your code in an if to check if content is higher than view:
if (([myView bounds].size.height - [myView contentSize].height) > 0)

Comment: This solution worked great for me; however, while testing my app I noticed that I'd get a crash if I called this code 3-4 times. Looks like you also want to remove the observer. I added this and it fixed the crash: 
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [textField removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize"];
}
 
I found this solution thanks to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7467414/81008

Comment: UITextView (and other UIKit classes) are not guaranteed to be KVO compliant. Relying on this could cause your code to break in future iOS versions. See this post by a member of the UIKit development team: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6051404/357641

Comment: I Prefer using `NSStringFromSelector(@selector(contentSize))` instead of just `@"contentSize"`. And don't forget to put the `removeObserver:forKeyPath:` to a try-catch statement!

Comment: with autolayout you have to use
let size = tv.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(tv.bounds), CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
instead of [tv contentSize]

Comment: This appears to be broken in iOS 9.0.2. However, a workaround exists.
Instead of setting the contentOffset, we can set the contentInset instead (Just change the last line of code in the observeValueForKeyPath method to):
` [tv setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(topCorrect,0,0,0)];`
Note: If we KVO the contentOffset, iOS 9 sets it to 0 at the last moment, overriding any changes to contentOffset.

Comment: Same code is not working in UITableViewCell  - (void)awakeFromNib {
    
    [self.textViewLarge addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
    [self.textView1 addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
    [self.textView2 addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

Comment: It is so frustrating that this cannot be achieved directly in the Storyboard

Answer (score 58):

Because [UIKit is not KVO compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6051404/357641), I decided to implement this as a subclass of `UITextView` which updates whenever the `contentSize` changes.

It's a slightly modified version of [Carlos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12591299/35690) which sets the `contentInset` instead of the `contentOffset`. In addition to [being compatible with iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33335640/35690), it also seems to be less buggy on iOS 8.4.

```
class VerticallyCenteredTextView: UITextView {
    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            var topCorrection = (bounds.size.height - contentSize.height * zoomScale) / 2.0
            topCorrection = max(0, topCorrection)
            contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topCorrection, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of updating the `contentInset`, I try resizing the textView by changing the constraints whenever the above `contentSize didSet` gets called and that also works.

Comment: Working fine for iOS 9.2. Just wanted to point out that scrolling MUST be enabled for this to work. If you want to ensure that programmatically (probably safer than expecting someone to set it correctly in the storyboard), just call `scrollEnabled = true` before calculating the `topCorrection` and, in case you still want to disable users to scroll, you will also need `userInteractionEnabled = false`. Also, a minor for copy-pasters: Xcode will require an `init` method in your subclassed UITextView.

Comment: One should take into account `layoutMargins` and write `var topCorrection = (bounds.size.height - contentSize.height * zoomScale + layoutMargins.top + layoutMargins.bottom) / 2.0`

Comment: this also works batter in table and collection views.

Answer (score 27):

If you don't want to use KVO you can also manually adjust offset with exporting this code to a function like this :

```
-(void)adjustContentSize:(UITextView*)tv{
    CGFloat deadSpace = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv contentSize].height);
    CGFloat inset = MAX(0, deadSpace/2.0);
    tv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(inset, tv.contentInset.left, inset, tv.contentInset.right);
}
```

and calling it in

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
    [self adjustContentSize:textView];
}
```

and every time you edit the text in the code. Don't forget to set the controller as the delegate

**Swift 3 version:**

```
func adjustContentSize(tv: UITextView){
    let deadSpace = tv.bounds.size.height - tv.contentSize.height
    let inset = max(0, deadSpace/2.0)
    tv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(inset, tv.contentInset.left, inset, tv.contentInset.right)
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    self.adjustContentSize(tv: textView)
}
```

Comment: this works as shown, but I can not initialize the text view upon cell appearing. Only works if I pass the delegates textView argument into the adjustContentSize(_:), not if I pass in the IBOutlet variable name. Any idea why this may be the case?

Comment: It's because things with x and y position like size, insets, are valid once the view has redrawn the view with autolayout constraint, so you can call adjustContentSize after the viewDidLayoutSubviews function in your controller and it should work

Comment: How to even use this, while working? Sorry, if I'm asking a dumb question. New to swift.

Comment: @Shyam TextviewDidChange is a delegate of UITextfield. If you don't know what is it, I suggest you to take a look at the delegate pattern because it's used in many scenarios in iOS. Basically, you have to set the delegate as your current view controller ( yourtextfield.delegate = self) and implement required functions (textViewDidChange in this case)

Comment: @Beninho85, thanks for your time. Yeah, got a hold of delegates. Well, my question should have been more detailed. I use a placeholder in a `UITextView`. And this adheres to auto layout. So, I would like to centre the placeholder vertically, in all views. But, if text is entered by the user, the placeholder is replaced, and the alignment should revert back to use the full area available. The vertical alignment is only for the placeholder. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, it's because my solution uses the Content Offset property of the textfield to adjust the current text to the middle of the UITextview each time the user types something. If you want to center the placeholder only, just call adjustContentSize function once after setting your placeholder text. I'm not sure about the behaviour after that, but normally you don't need the delegate because it's used only for adjust text when typed. If it doesn't work, just try to reset the offset at 0 or something like that in the textviewdidchange property.

Comment: This is the only solution works even in Xcode 10 Swift 4+

Answer (score 20):

For iOS 9.0.2. we'll need to set the contentInset instead. If we KVO the contentOffset, iOS 9.0.2 sets it to 0 at the last moment, overriding the changes to contentOffset.

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    UITextView *tv = object;
    CGFloat topCorrect = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv     contentSize].height * [tv zoomScale])/2.0;
    topCorrect = ( topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect );
    [tv setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(topCorrect,0,0,0)];
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:NO];
    [questionTextView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
}
```

I used 0,0, and 0 for the left,bottom and right edge insets respectively. Make sure to calculate those as well for your use case.

Comment: Thanks!, it works but had to use `setTextContainerInset` instead of `setContentInset`

Answer (score 17):

It is the simple task using `NSLayoutManager` to get real text size of the `NSTextContainer`

```
class VerticallyCenteredTextView: UITextView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    
        let rect = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
        let topInset = (bounds.size.height - rect.height) / 2.0
        textContainerInset.top = max(0, topInset)
    }
}
```

Don't use `contentSize` and `contentInset` in your final calculations.

Comment: This works great. Make sure you set correct class  on the xib identity inspector. https://d.pr/i/hLQe9C

Answer (score 13):

Here's a `UITextView` extension that centers content vertically:

```
extension UITextView {

    func centerVertically() {
        let fittingSize = CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: CGFloat.max)
        let size = sizeThatFits(fittingSize)
        let topOffset = (bounds.size.height - size.height * zoomScale) / 2
        let positiveTopOffset = max(0, topOffset)
        contentOffset.y = -positiveTopOffset
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this need to be called after the view has been laid out, I imagine?

Comment: The max should be calculated between 0 and topOffset because 1 might cause the clipping of text from bottom in case the contentSize is same as the textView size.

Comment: cuts off text on iOS 10 if there are line breaks

Answer (score 11):

You can set it up directly with only constraints:

There are 3 constraints i added to align text vertically and horizontally in constraints as below :

[image]

1. Make height 0 and add constraints greater than
2. Add vertically align to parent constraints
3. Add horizontally align to parent constraints

[image]

Comment: This works well if you disable scrolling on the UITextView

Comment: This worked for me, however adding these constraints xcode will throw an error that there is some ambiguity. To silence it I added top and bottom constraints equal to 0 with 250 as priority.

Answer (score 8):

I just created a custom vertically centered text view in Swift 3:

```
class VerticallyCenteredTextView: UITextView {
    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            var topCorrection = (bounds.size.height - contentSize.height * zoomScale) / 2.0
            topCorrection = max(0, topCorrection)
            contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topCorrection, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Ref: https://geek-is-stupid.github.io/2017-05-15-how-to-center-text-vertically-in-a-uitextview/

Comment: Didn't work....this callback gets called 5-6 times per one screen appearance, and the calculations are not identical each time....it's not good at all please don't use

Comment: This is a really elegant solution. It worked perfectly for a UIViewRepresentable in SwiftUI that responds to a MagnificationGesture changing font size dynamically. Bravo!

Answer (score 7):

```
func alignTextVerticalInTextView(textView :UITextView) {

    let size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(textView.bounds), CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))

    var topoffset = (textView.bounds.size.height - size.height * textView.zoomScale) / 2.0
    topoffset = topoffset < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topoffset

    textView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -topoffset)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I have a textview that I'm using with autolayout and with setting the `lineFragmentPadding` and `textContainerInset` to zero. None of the solutions above worked in my situation. However, this works for me. Tested with iOS 9

```
@interface VerticallyCenteredTextView : UITextView
@end

@implementation VerticallyCenteredTextView

-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [self recenter];
}

-(void)recenter{
    // using self.contentSize doesn't work correctly, have to calculate content size
    CGSize contentSize = [self sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    CGFloat topCorrection = (self.bounds.size.height - contentSize.height * self.zoomScale) / 2.0;
    self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -topCorrection);
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what was the need for me.

Comment: @user3777977 Just copy your answer here.


Add to Carlos answer, just in case you have text in tv bigger then tv size you don't need to recenter text, so change this code:

`tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};`


to this:


`if ([tv contentSize].height < [tv bounds].size.height) {
     tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
} `

Answer (score 5):

I have also this problem and I solved it with a `UITableViewCell` with `UITextView`. I created method in a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass, property `statusTextView`:

```
- (void)centerTextInTextView
{
    CGFloat topCorrect = ([self.statusTextView bounds].size.height - [self.statusTextView contentSize].height * [self.statusTextView zoomScale])/2.0;
    topCorrect = ( topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect );
    self.statusTextView.contentOffset = (CGPoint){ .x = 0, .y = -topCorrect };
```

And call this method in methods:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This solution worked for me with no issues, you can try it.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3:**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        textField.frame = self.view.bounds

        var topCorrect : CGFloat = (self.view.frame.height / 2) - (textField.contentSize.height / 2)
        topCorrect = topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect
        textField.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topCorrect,0,0,0)

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add to Carlos answer, just in case you have text in tv bigger then tv size you don't need to recenter text, so change this code:

```
tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
```

to this:

```
if ([tv contentSize].height < [tv bounds].size.height) {
     tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Auto-layout solution:

1. Create a UIView that acts as a container for the UITextView.
2. Add the following constraints:

   - TextView: Align leading space to: Container
   - TextView: Align trailing space to: Container
   - TextView: Align center Y to: Container
   - TextView: Equal Height to: Container, Relation: ≤

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for me. Even these four constraints are not enough. Can I somehow set the textField to 'stick around' the text content?

Comment: What happens if you put the container on the same level as the text view in the hierarchy? - So, instead of it acting as an actual container, it's just a placeholder located at the same location.

Comment: This solution also requires auto-resizeable text view - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868117/uitextview-that-expands-to-text-using-auto-layout

Comment: This solution is way better!

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code, no observer mandatorily required. observer throws error sometimes when view deallocates.
You can keep this code in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear or in viewDidAppear anywhere.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        UITextView *tv = txtviewDesc;
        CGFloat topCorrect = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv contentSize].height * [tv zoomScale])/2.0;
        topCorrect = ( topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect );
        tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried to remove the observer too in viewWillDisappear & viewDidDisappear, then also it's crashing sometimes.

Comment: Rather than setting observer, this process is simple and flexible to keep anywhere.

Comment: You can remove the observer in the `dealloc` method, `-(void)dealloc {}`

Comment: `dealloc` is not allowed anymore in ARC projects. :)

Comment: The dealloc method is allowed in ARC projects, just don't call `[super dealloc];`

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this: first of all, I embedded the UITextView in an UIView (this should work for mac OS too). Then I pinned all four sides of the external UIView to the sides of its container, giving it a shape and size similar or equal to that of the UITextView. Thus I had a proper container for the UITextView. Then I pinned the left and right borders of the UITextView to the sides of the UIView, and gave the UITextView a height. Finally, I centered the UITextView vertically in the UIView. Bingo :) now the UITextView is vertically centered in the UIView, hence text inside the UITextView is vertically centered too.

Answer (score -1):

UITextView+VerticalAlignment.h

```
//  UITextView+VerticalAlignment.h
//  (c) The Internet 2015
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UITextView (VerticalAlignment)

- (void)alignToVerticalCenter;
- (void)disableAlignment;

@end
```

UITextView+VerticalAlignment.m

```
#import "UITextView+VerticalAlignment.h"

@implementation UITextView (VerticalAlignment)

- (void)alignToVerticalCenter {
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    UITextView *tv = object;
    CGFloat topCorrect = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv contentSize].height * [tv zoomScale])/2.0;
    topCorrect = ( topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect );
    tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
}

- (void)disableAlignment {
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize"];
}
@end
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this problem by creating extension to center height vertically.

**SWIFT 5:**

```
extension UITextView {
    func centerContentVertically() {
        let fitSize = CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let size = sizeThatFits(fitSize)
        let heightOffset = (bounds.size.height - size.height * zoomScale) / 2
        let positiveTopOffset = max(0, heightOffset)
        contentOffset.y = -positiveTopOffset
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Solution for iOS10 in RubyMotion:

```
class VerticallyCenteredTextView < UITextView

    def init
        super
    end

    def layoutSubviews
        self.recenter
    end

    def recenter
        contentSize = self.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, Float::MAX))
        topCorrection = (self.bounds.size.height - contentSize.height * self.zoomScale) / 2.0;
        topCorrection = 0 if topCorrection < 0
        self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topCorrection,  0, 0, 0)
    end

end
```