# iOS 7 UITextView vertical alignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitextview, vertical-alignment

How is that possible that my editable `UITextView` (placed inside a straightforward UIViewController inside a `UISplitView` that acts as delegate for the `UITextView`) is not showing text from the beginning but after something like 6-7 lines?

[image: Screenshot]

I didn't set any particular autolayout or something similar, trying to delete text doesn't help (so no hidden chars or something).

I'm using iOS 7 on iPad, in storyboard looks good... 
The problem is the same on iOS simulator and real devices. I'm getting mad :P

Here's some code. This is the ViewController `viewDidLoad()`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.itemTextField.delegate = self;
    self.itemTextField.text = NSLocalizedString(@"NEWITEMPLACEHOLDER", nil);
    self.itemTextField.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; //optional
}
```

And here are the overridden functions for the `UITextView` I'm using some code I've found on StackOverflow to simulate a placeholder for the view (the same stuff on iPhone version of the storyboard works fine)...

```
// UITextView placeholder
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"NEWITEMPLACEHOLDER", nil)]) {
        textView.text = @"";
        textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //optional
    }
    [textView becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        textView.text = NSLocalizedString(@"NEWITEMPLACEHOLDER", nil);
        textView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; //optional
    }
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    int len = textView.text.length;
    charCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %i",  NSLocalizedString(@"CHARCOUNT", nil),len];
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: the lightblue is the UITextVIew background color?

Comment: Yes, I set it in storyboard for making it clear in the screenshot. By the way, the problem is there even with the default background color.

Comment: This has been heavily modified from the original question, which was 'How can I vertically align a UITextView'.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try to call `-sizeToFit` after passing the text. This answer could be useful to [Vertically align text within a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel).

[UPDATE]
I update this answer o make it more readable. 
The issue is that from iOS7, container view controllers such as UINavigationController or UITabbarController can change the content insets of scroll views (or views that inherit from it), to avoid content overlapping. This happens only if the scrollview is the main view or the first subviews. To avoid that you should disable this behavior by setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to NO, or overriding this method to return NO.

Comment: Not working. The `UITextView` is resized to something like 30 x 20 pixels and no text is shown.

Comment: Are you using attributed string?

Comment: Ok, maybe lorik pointed me to the right direction. The inset is due to the fact that UITextField has scrool capabilities, since iOS7 in sotryboard each sort of scrollview is automatically inset of the size of statusbar+navbar (in UINavController). Probably here you put a constraint form the top, that fix the "top distance" but you didn't unselect the automatic edge option. So check on storyboard for this VC and unselect adjust scroll view insets option.

Answer (score 15):

I got through the same kind of issue.

Solved it by disabling the automatic scrollView insets adjustement :

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")){
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO; // Avoid the top UITextView space, iOS7 (~bug?)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's the "code way" of a similar storyboard property!

Answer (score 7):

This is a fairly common problem, so I would create a simple UITextView subclass, so that you can re-use it and use it in IB.

I would used the contentInset instead, making sure to gracefully handle the case where the contentSize is larger than the bounds of the textView

```
@interface BSVerticallyCenteredTextView : UITextView

@end

@implementation BSVerticallyCenteredTextView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:  (NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:  (NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentSize"])
    {
        UITextView *tv = object;
        CGFloat deadSpace = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv contentSize].height);
        CGFloat inset = MAX(0, deadSpace/2.0);
        tv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(inset, tv.contentInset.left, inset, tv.contentInset.right);
    }  
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize"];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4):

use -`observerForKeyPath` with `contentSize` KeyPath

Look some code at My Blog (don't focus on **Thai** Language)

[http://www.macbaszii.com/2012/10/ios-dev-uitextview-vertical-alignment.html](http://www.macbaszii.com/2012/10/ios-dev-uitextview-vertical-alignment.html?q=vertical)

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Kiattisak, I've implemented vertical alignment as a category over `UITextView` so that you can control the **vertical** alignment of legacy `UITextView`.

You can find it as a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/toms972/8330377).

Comment: Just be sure to remove the key value observer when the VC gets deallocated

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with iOS 8.1, and none of these suggestions worked.

What *did* work was to go into the Storyboard, and drag my `UITableView` or `UITextView` so that it was no longer the first subview of my screen's `UIView`.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/852308/Bug-in-XCode-Vertical-Gap-Above-UITableView

It seems to be linked to having a `UIView` embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

Bug ?  Bug ?  Did I say "bug" ...?

;-)

Answer (score 1):

Swift version of Tanguy.G's answer:

```
if(UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion >= "7.0") {
            self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false; // Avoid the top UITextView space, iOS7 (~bug?)
  }
```

Comment: Note too, that you often have to call for layout:  `view.layoutIfNeeded()`.  It's very annoying and exceptionally badly done in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Check top content inset of textView in `-viewDidLoad`:

```
NSLog(@"NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets(self.itemTextField.contentInset) = %@", NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets(self.itemTextField.contentInset));
```

Reset it in storyboard if it is not zero

Comment: `NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets(self.itemTextField.contentInset) = {0, 0, 0, 0}`
No luck.

Comment: Log `self.itemTextField.contentOffset`

Comment: self.itemTextField.contentOffset = null

Comment: Changing the field.contentOffset was the only solution that worked for me. (iOS 7.0)