# Setting the UITextView Text to the Beginning of the UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am using a `UITextView` and assigning some text in my code but for some reason it always starts after 5-6 lines. The `UITextView` is an `AttributedTextView` or allows Attributed strings.

[image]

```
 self.bodyTextView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
 self.bodyTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cochin" size:17];
 self.bodyTextView.text = @"This is written by Joe. This is written by Moo. This is written by Qoo";
```

Comment: try setting the UITextView's `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to NO.  See if that does anything.

Comment: There is no such property on the UITextView control.

Comment: well bugger.  I got that answer from http://stackoverflow.com/a/19468461/1671729.  Give it a look and see if it answers you at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not help! I am not using ScrollView. I am using a UITextView and the bottom is UITabbar. I cannot even find the property you are mentioning.

Comment: Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18932245/1671729.  Apparently that property is on the containing view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18932245/1671729)

`A text view is a scroll view. iOS 7 will add a content offset automatically to scroll views, as it assumes they will want to scroll up behind the nav bar and title bar.`

`To prevent this, override the new method on UIViewController, automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets, and return NO.`

It deals with the Navigation bar overlapping the UIViewController's view's frame.  When that is set to no then the UIViewController does not adjust anything to avoid the top navigation bar.

Instead of subclassing and overloading, you can just set the property to no.

```
(UIViewController).automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```