# Text loading at bottom of UITextView

Tags: ios7, xcode5, uitextview

I'm trying to display some text in a UITextView, but it seems to load it in the middle of the textview whereas I'd like it to align via top. I tried following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468417/ios-7-uitextview-vertical-alignment), but using `sizeToFit` and my NavContoller's `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property was already set to `NO`.

Here's a screenshot (see how there's a bit of text at the bottom):

[image]

My code is here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // If descLong is not present, use descShort
    if (!self.product.descLong) {
        self.descLong.text = self.product.descLong;
    } else {
        self.descLong.text = self.product.descShort;
    }
    [self.descLong sizeToFit];

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unchecked "Adjust Scroll View Insets" in the attributes section of storyboard and the issue was fixed.

Comment: Where is this fabled setting?  I see it not.