# UIViewController gets offset when I go back to it

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that has a `UIScrollView` as a root view defined and added like this

```
[self.view addSubview:mainScrollView];
UIScrollView *mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
```

I offset by 64 to start from the `NavigationController` (20 status bar + 44 navigation bar) and it's all OK until now.
Then I add another `ViewController` and when i go back the mainScrollView is offset in y by 64 points from the navigation controller. Why does this happen ?

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: If you're using a fullscreen `UIScrollView` with no other views in your view controller, you can set `self.view = mainScrollView` instead of using `addSubview:`, then the view controller should offset everything for you automatically...

Comment: I just tried what you suggested but everything disappears, even the navigation bar when i click back. I do have other views inside `mainScrollView`

Comment: Are you doing anything on `viewWillDisappear`? Also, if setting `self.view`, are you doing it in `loadView`?

Comment: I dont have a `viewWillDisappear` and I'm setting self.view on `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Try change `viewDidLoad` to `loadView`...

Comment: Its the same, the offset happens again

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: before http://storage.workupload.com/image/7EdPsvVs and after http://storage.workupload.com/image/NjDkMUce

Comment: Is your navigation bar translucent?

Comment: No the bar itself. Try without offsetting the view manually like this `CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)`

Comment: if I do that my cover picture starts behind the navigation bar and then when I come again here it starts exactly from the navigation bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably is due to a wrong combination of those properties:

1. [automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets)
2. [edgesForExtendedLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/edgesForExtendedLayout)
3. [extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars)
4. translucency of the navigation bar

The first one adds an inset, if the first view or first subview of the VC is a scrollview or a view that inherits from it (such as a tableview). The second tell the main view if it should lie under the navbar or tab bar that's where the "adjust" is useful.
Here a similar answer [iOS 7 UITextView vertical alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468417/ios-7-uitextview-vertical-alignment/19468461#19468461)

Comment: I didnt use any of those 3 and my navigationbar is lightcontent not transluscent.

Comment: Maybe you just think you aren't, some properties are set to YES by default, check on interface builder if you have the checkbox on automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets, give it a shot.. or if you are doing programmatically, force it in init or viewDidLoad

Comment: I did it :D it was the first one and also @Jonathon was helped with the line of code too

Answer (score 2):

This is the same probably can see when you add a `UITableView` to a `UIViewController` that has `Under Top Bars` property checked

[image]

You can consider this a "hack" or not but try unchecking that box and see if it fixes your problem.

If it does, then it should be a matter of setting the proper `EdgeInset`.  One you get that part fixed, you could then just re-enable "under top bars" if you actually want/need it.

Comment: I dont use neither Storyboard nor Xib, everything by code

Comment: then `self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;` `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;` - i think this goes in viewDidLoad..

Answer (score 0):

Your Scroll view is started from y=64. It may be the cause offset of y=64 when you navigate on another view controller.
Kinjal

Comment: Yes Sherlock but "Why" is the question

Answer (score 0):

It's rather hard to get what is the reason exactly.

What I would do is to implement the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method of the `UIViewController` and break into it to get all the metrics of your `self.view` and your `mainScrollView`.documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews)

With those information we can find what can be the problem.

Either to try something to go around it or maybe find the root cause I would also try to set the `mainScrollView` as `the UIViewController` view:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    UIScrollView *mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
    self.view = mainScrollView;
}
```

Another solution can be to adjust the y offset of the mainScrollView in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.mainscrollView.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```