# If UITextView is first sub-view then a big space will appear between the top of the view and the start of the text

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitextview, uistoryboard

It appears that like in native Xcode, in Xamarin studio for ioS if your first sub-view in a view hierarchy is a UITextView, then adding a top-layout constraint to this view will cause a large block of empty space to appear at the top of the scroll view.

This is similar to the Xcode version of the question here

[iOS 7 UITextView vertical alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468417/ios-7-uitextview-vertical-alignment)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this programmatically by adapting

[Tanguy-G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882754)'s answer for native Objective-C by setting AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets to false in the constructor of my view controller.

```
    public MyLovelyViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        this.AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
    }
```

EDIT: If you are setting any other aspects of the text view in question programmatically, make sure to call

`this.AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;`

after any other adjustments, otherwise the space will reappear, e.g:

```
    confirmSummary.Editable = false;
    confirmSummary.Selectable = false;
    this.AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
```

(I did this in the override of ViewDidLoad)