# Vertical Text Alignment in UITextView Xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitextview

I want a centre aligned text in a UITextView. Just like Whatsapp Type a status page.

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468417/ios-7-uitextview-vertical-alignment

Comment: @ColeXia I have done it by making the textview transparent and on the text changed event of textview I have added the textview text to a label and label can be placed at the centre

Comment: why don't you use label directly?

Comment: @ColeXia But then, where would I write ?? I need to open keyboard on tap

Comment: okay, i got it.