# UITextView in UITableView disappears when run on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I have a `UITableView` with a `UITextView` inside. When I run it on the simulator, the `textView` disapears. Here are some pictures to illustrate what's going on:

Stroyboard:
[image]

(The `textView` is in green.)

[image]
(`textViews` constraints)

When I run it on the simulator:

[image] (The `textView` disapears.)

The `textView`'s height will be dynamic. So I tried creating a height constraint with the relation to 'greater than or equal', and the `textView's` height didn't change.

(Note: when I add a `textField`, (not a `textView`), it works fine.)

> **Question:**
>
> Why does the `textView` disappear when I run it on the simulator, and
>   how can I fix it?

Comment: What height are you setting the row to? Why not put the text view in a modal and present it on demand?

Comment: `uitableviewautomaticdimension`

Comment: UITextViews normally don't have an intrinsic contentSize, so they can't be sized automatically. They are basically scrollViews, you have to tell AutoLayout how big the textView frame should be, it will only calculate its contentSize. But according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21287306/457406) you could try to set scrollEnabled to NO.

Comment: Thanks! It works! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: After struggling for hours for a solution i found your reply! Thanks, please make an answer!!! @MatthiasBauch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you set your UITextView to "not" scrollable:

```
[textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

it will be able to calculate an intrinsic size, thus allowing auto layout to move the other elements by itself, then it's up to you to setup the constraints right.