# Moving UILabel dynamically based on UITextView contents - Using Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, storyboard, autolayout

Using storyboard, I am trying to put a `UILabel` below `UITextView`. Content of `UITextView` can grow based on user input. I want my `UILabel` to reposition its Y value based on `UITextView` contents. I've tried fixing vertical spacing between `UITextView` and `UILabel` but that is not helping.

What else I shall be doing to crack this?

Comment: you can change your label position in delegate of textView : changeCharactersInRange:

Comment: I want to do it via storyboard only. Have done it through code. Wanted to explore auto layout and storyboard options.

Comment: If you [configure your text view to not scroll vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21287306/77567), it will be able to resize itself to fit its text, and you should be able to constrain your label to the bottom of the text view.

Answer (score 0):

You should use constraints explicitly. The label in particular must have the constraint "top space to Textview" set to N points. Then set an outlet in your view controller from the constraint "top space to Textview" and change that constraint to resize uilabel Y position.

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelYConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

func changeLabelPosition(sender: AnyObject) {

    labelYConstraint.constant = newY
}
```

Let me know if you need more details