# UITextView wrong content position with auto layout

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, swift2, uitextview

I have a UITextView in UIViewController with auto layout:

[image]

The TextView size changes proportionally in accordance to the View (for example on rotation, or run on different dispositive iPhone 4s..6s).

Unfortunately the content text doesn't show from first line:

[image]

I suppose that the content inset is wrong but I don't have a solution.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: thanks for the support...i added the constraints in storyboard, my view size is 600 x 600 (any,any)  I didn't write code , I used the sample text "Lorem ipsum..." repeated several times

Comment: It's hard to say with the info you've given so far, and, without seeing the Interface Builder storyboard setup. Some more questions: *the content text doesn't show from first line* - do you mean, **only the first line is shown**? Or, **the top/first line of the text view is empty**? (or something else?) Also, is it only wrong in *some* conditions? Or is it always wrong?

Comment: i added any images, thanks

Comment: Take a look at my comments in the answer... try deleting those constraints, and, for the screen shot of the app running, can the text scroll up and down? (when trying the scroll that's when you'll see the "scroll bars").

Answer (score 0):

I don't use *Interface Builder* - so I'm sure someone can correct me if I'm wrong, or, see the mistake if I've missed it...

But, from your screen shot (resolution is a bit low) it looks like you've got vertical constraints when positioning the text view: there's a value showing a spacing between the view and *Top Layout Guide* (and again for the bottom layout guide). You could just delete these...

Specifically:

- `Top space to` *equals* `135`
- `Bottom space to` *equals* `106`

As for your second screen shot, I'm not sure if it's a different device to the image on the right... but maybe the sample text just doesn't fit in the view, and it's *scrolled* to the bottom of the text. That would make it look like the top text is *cut off*, because it's *clipped* by the top of the `UITextView`.

Comment: i need these spaces (top, bottom).. and for the second screen shot is the same simulator: on the left my problem, on the right i scroll to top position manually

Comment: Ok, so, in your second image, the one showing two screen shots of the app running... are those images two different devices? Is the device on the left smaller than the device on the right? If yes... then, the text is simply too big to fit in the `UITextView`, in which case it has scrolled down. You'll be able to scroll it up and down. **Note**: the size of the text won't automatically change for smaller/larger devices. So, the same text/content won't necessarily fit on one device, even if it fits on another...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I tried all of the work-arounds to `setContentOffset` and/or `scrollRangeToVisible` to no avail.

I was inspired by this SO post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21287306/610550

I ended up disabling scrolling on the textView on the storyboard, and then using `self.textView.scrollEnabled = true` in `viewDidLoad()`. It worked perfectly!