# Swift Dynamically growing a cell depending on the text length

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a TableViewController which contains 2 sections:
Section 1 - is a cell which is loaded from a xib file.  This cell just contains a TextView.
Section 2 - Contains multiple cells populated from an Array.

The section 1 only exists if the master (previous) UITableView cell you select contains a certain piece of data.

All of the above works as expected, below is the parent view.  The list of items come from a database, some items have a description, and some do not.  For example below this image, you'll see the view is 'Classic Starters' is selected.  Then below that, you'll see the view if 'Stir Frys' is selected.  Stri Frys contains a description:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, what I want is, the description cell which is shows on the Stir Frys page, to automatically grow depending on the length of the text inside it.  So if a description is 10 lines long, it will grow to show all 10 lines.

Does this have to be done programmatically, or is their a feature in XCode I'm missing ?

Comment: Give UITableViewAutomaticDimension in heightForRowAt delegate method for the cell containing description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** you need to do is to set `estimatedRowSize` to a value that best estimates most common size, and `rowSize` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

In your case, since except the first one all the other cells are supposed to be the same, you can use the height of the rest of the cells as the `estimatedRowHeight`.

You don't have to implement `heightForRowAt` at all.

The **second** step you need to do is to setup proper constraints on the cells. That means you have to constrain the contents of the cell to the left, right, top and bottom of the cell, so that when contents grow, the cell will need to grow, too. Common mistake is to forget to constrain bottom, so then the cell does not grow and the contents leak through the bottom of the cell.

**Third**, since your dynamic cell contains `UITextView`, you need to make sure that it will grow with its text. That is not automatic. To achieve that, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21287306/2912282), this should suffice (in the cell):

```
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

If you are using storyboard, just uncheck scroll enabled.

Answer (score 3):

You can use UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

1)
Set properties estimatedRowHeight and rowHeight of your tableview, in viewDidLoad for example. Like this :

```
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

2) Return UITableViewAutomaticDimension in your heightForRowAt delegate method :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Comment: Won't this set all the cells to that height ?  Also what about making it dynamic, each description might be different for example

Comment: The property estimatedRowHeight only improve tableView loading performance, I put 50 arbitrarily but that's not really important. Here, the important thing is UITableViewAutomaticDimension, you must return it for your description cells.

Comment: Ah right, I'll try implement this now then.  I'll accept your answer.  Thanks