# The best way to display a long text

Tags: ios, swift

Can you please let me know what is the best way to display a long text in the app? I would like to display text about the company. Now I do have tableView and inside of the cell just a normal UILabel. Is it ok?
Thanks!

Comment: How long is long? How many characters does your text contain?

Comment: My favorite for those things is a TextView. Scrollable and just plain or attributed text. Always use this for info sections or protocols.

Comment: you might find this question interesting for your task: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48423558/2912282

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its ok to display long text in the UILabel. In Label you can also use attributed string in case you need anytime. You need to make sure dynamic height of the table row with the UILabel content. Use 0 as number of lines for the UILabel and TextWrap as the Line break option. Make sure you have good constraints for your label in the cell row.
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add text line height programmatically to UILabel?

Comment: Yes, You can put Height constraint with equalTo.....  on the label's height,.. but watch it carefully in different devices and make sure it won't truncate your text for bigger text...