# UITextView aligning text vertically center

Tags: ios, uitextview

I want to align text vertically center in `UItextView`.

I am using following code

```
UITextView *tv = object;
     CGFloat topCorrect = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv contentSize].height * [tv zoomScale])/2.0;
     topCorrect = ( topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect );
     tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect}
```

;

Somehow this doesn't work in iOS 5 as the contentSize returned there is different what I get in iOS6.

Any Idea why `contentSize` of the same textView is different in iOS 5 and iOS 6?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center text vertically in a UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591192/center-text-vertically-in-a-uitextview)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add an observer for the contentSize key value of the UITextView when the view loaded :-

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  [textField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
  [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Adjust the contentOffset every time the contentSize value change :-

```
 -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
 UITextView *tv = object;
 CGFloat topCorrect = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv contentSize].height * [tv zoomScale])/2.0;
 topCorrect = ( topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect );
 tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
}
```

Hope it helps you...

You may take guide from

https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView

Comment: This doesn't keep the text constantly centered vertically because if the UITextView is resized (for example, when the keyboard appears) then the content in the UITextView reverts to top alignment.

Comment: This is a great bit of code apart from its value as a keypath observer. Thanks.

Comment: I had a crash while using this code in a `UITableView`. Working well on ios8 but also needs to remove observer after alignment is done. Add this line as last line of `observeValueForKeyPath` method: `[tv removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize"];`

Answer (score 5):

try this on observeValueForKeyPath method on iOS7:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
    {
UITextView *tv = object;

CGFloat height = [tv bounds].size.height;
CGFloat contentheight;

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7")) {
    contentheight = [tv sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(tv.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)].height;
    NSLog(@"iOS7; %f %f", height, contentheight);
}else{
    contentheight = [tv contentSize].height;
    NSLog(@"iOS6; %f %f", height, contentheight);
}

CGFloat topCorrect = height - contentheight;
topCorrect = (topCorrect <0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect);
tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
}
```

to be defined:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified Arpit's solution so it can fit with expanding textview contentView

```
static NSString *const kContentOffsetKeyPath = @"contentOffset";

-(void)viewDidLoad {
     [self.replyTextView addObserver:self
                         forKeyPath:kContentOffsetKeyPath
                            options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew)
                            context:NULL];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:kContentOffsetKeyPath]) {
        // To keep scrolling to bottom while typing and text content view is larger than maximum limit
        if (textView.contentSize.height > singleLineHeight) {
            UITextView *textView = object;
            CGFloat topCorrect = ([textView bounds].size.height - [textView contentSize].height * [textView zoomScale]) / 2.0;
            CGFloat fineTune = -3.0;
            topCorrect = (topCorrect < fineTune ? fineTune : topCorrect);
            // To avoid recursion
            [textView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:kContentOffsetKeyPath];
            textView.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
            // add observer back
            [textView addObserver:self
                       forKeyPath:kContentOffsetKeyPath
                          options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew)
                          context:NULL];
        }
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self.replyTextView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:kContentOffsetKeyPath];
    }
```