# Textview Center Text Alignment IOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath   ofObject:(id)object   change:(NSDictionary *)change   context:(void *)context 
{
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    UITextView *tv = object;
    CGFloat topCorrect = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv contentSize].height * [tv zoomScale])  / 2.0;
    topCorrect = ( topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect );
    tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
}
```

I am calling it like this in Viewdidload

```
[myTextView1 addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
```

Comment: Is this vertical alignment? Is there any reason you're using a UITextView over a UILabel? The label will do this for you for free.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024375/uitextview-alligining-text-vertically-center?rq=1

Answer (score 13):

```
textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 2):

try this on iOS7:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
    {
UITextView *tv = object;

CGFloat height = [tv bounds].size.height;
CGFloat contentheight;

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7")) {
    contentheight = [tv sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(tv.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)].height;
    NSLog(@"iOS7; %f %f", height, contentheight);
}else{
    contentheight = [tv contentSize].height;
    NSLog(@"iOS6; %f %f", height, contentheight);
}

CGFloat topCorrect = height - contentheight;
topCorrect = (topCorrect <0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect);
tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
}
```

to be defined:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

Comment: This works great except for when the content fits on one line. then it aligns it with the bottom. If you add, ` CGFloat topCorrect = (height - contentheight * [tv zoomScale])/2.0;`, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For swift:

```
        itemTextView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath:"contentSize", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
```

and

```
    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String!, ofObject object: AnyObject!, change: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    var tv : UITextView = object as UITextView;
    var height = tv.bounds.size.height;
    var contentheight = tv.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(tv.frame.size.width,1000)).height


    var topCorrect : CGFloat = height - contentheight;
    if(topCorrect < 0) {
        topCorrect = 0
    }
    tv.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -topCorrect/2)

}
```