# Center the text in a UITextView, vertically and horizontally

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have a grouped table view with one cell. In this cell I'm putting a `UITextView` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and I instantly make this first Responder.

My problem is: When I start typing, the text is left-justified, not centered horizontally and vertically as I want. This is on iOS 7.

How can I center the text?

Comment: have you set alignment and post your code if so

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I resolve this issue by observing the contentsize of UITextView, when there is any change in the contentSize, update the contentOffset.

Add observer as follows:

```
[textview addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
```

Handle the observer action as follows:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
     UITextView *txtview = object;
     CGFloat topoffset = ([txtview bounds].size.height - [txtview contentSize].height * [txtview zoomScale])/2.0;
     topoffset = ( topoffset < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topoffset );
     txtview.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topoffset};
}
```

To make the textview text horizontally center, select the textview from .xib class and go to the library and in that set Alignment as center.

Enjoy. :)

Comment: That's what I was searching for, thank you very much!
Just one more question: Before I start typing, it is aligned to the bottom of the tableview cell (cursor is on the bottom). When I start typing, it is perfectly aligned. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: If you add an observer, don't forget to remove it: [self.messageTextView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize"];

Comment: changing contentOffset only seems to work if the text view's "Selectable" flag is checked

Comment: Wow.  I've been banging my head for two days trying to get my textview to present a newline smoothly.  This is awesome.  I have my textView embedded in a TableFooter, and for some reason I have to resize the textView twice, before and after I use your method above.  I really don't understand why setting contentOffset can't be done in textViewDidChange, but it seems to only take affect after the second character on a newline...Thanks

Comment: Code is clearly copy-pasted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/12591299/603977 with two variable names changed.

Answer (score 1):

Very good solution! This is a `Swift` + `Interface Builder` solution so that you can enable it in IB.

I'll put it as part of the `LSwift` library.

```
extension UITextView {
    @IBInspectable var align_middle_vertical: Bool {
        get {
            return false    //  TODO
        }
        set (f) {
            self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath:"contentSize", options:.New, context:nil)
        }
    }
    override public func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject:AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if let textView = object as? UITextView {
            var y: CGFloat = (textView.bounds.size.height - textView.contentSize.height * textView.zoomScale)/2.0;
            if y < 0 {
                y = 0
            }
            textView.content_y = -y
        }
    }
}

public extension UIScrollView {
    public var content_x: CGFloat {
        set(f) {
            contentOffset.x = f
        }
        get {
            return contentOffset.x
        }
    }
    public var content_y: CGFloat {
        set(f) {
            contentOffset.y = f
        }
        get {
            return contentOffset.y
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `textView.content_y` I don't seem to understand?

Comment: Sorry @AbubakarOladeji should be `contentOffset.y`.